# Non-primitive user preferences - best practice

Tags: android

I need to store Objects as user preferences, primarily Hashmaps and ArrayLists. Up to now I have been serializing to JSON string and then deserializing as necessary. This has become very onerous - is there a better way to store non-primitive items in user prefs?

Comment: Why is it onerous?  You would have to serialise anyway to store in preferences.  A typical pattern is to create a class to abstract the data and include serialisation/deserialisation methods.  It should be easy.

Comment: @Simon Thanks, will give normal serialization a go. Asking why working with JSON in Android is onerous is equivalent to asking why computing with an Abacus is onerous.

Comment: +1 just for the smile!  I get your drift now.  Parcelable is probably a good route, easy to imeplement and is certainly higher performance if you are dealing with objects of any significance.  Nicely commented example -http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/